# Adding a ROS node

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a ROS node by simply doing some scripting in Python. Now, when I do rosnode list, it displays the list of all the active nodes. Now, I want to know how can I add the node to the list of already developed nodes ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241304/adding-a-ros-node/) by [muscles](https://answers.ros.org/users/24958/muscles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosnode list` lists the **running** ROS nodes (I'm not sure what you mean by "developed")

if you want your node to appear in `rosnode list` you just run it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0